# Чат на Java

Tags: java

Хочу написать простой чат на Java сокетах без многопоточности.
 1. Не очень понимаю как происходит соединение сокетом с другим компьютером, если передачей сокету ip, то как делать соединение по умолчанию при динамическом ip.
 2. Какие классы ввода вывода использовать.

Comment: 1. надо сервер, к которому эти динамические будут подключатся 2. какие знаешь?)

Comment: Поищите лучше библиотеку для работы с сокетами, я когда-то находил, но было давненько, поэтому точно не скажу название. Их не много, так что не заблудитесь)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нужен клиент и сервер, клиенты подключаются к серверу, а он транслирует полученные сообщения всем подключенным клиентам.
серверная часть:

```
public class Server {

    static ServerSocket socket;
    public static List<ConnectedClient> clients = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        socket = new ServerSocket(2000);

        while (true) {
            ConnectedClient client = new ConnectedClient(socket.accept());
            clients.add(client);
            client.start();
        }
    }
}

public class ConnectedClient extends Thread {
    private Socket sock;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private PrintWriter output;

    public ConnectedClient(Socket s) throws IOException {
        sock = s;
        System.out.println("new user connected from " + s.getInetAddress().toString());
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        output = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (sock.isConnected()) {
                String readed = input.readLine();
                for (CinnectedClient c : server.clients) {
                    c.send(readed);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            System.out.println("user disconnected from " + sock.getInetAddress().toString());
        }
    }

    public void send(String s) throws IOException {
        output.println(s);
        output.flush();
    }
}
```

клиентская часть:
сокет для подключения к серверу:

```
Socket s = new Socket(<IP сервера>, <порт подключения>);
```

аналогично серверу, берем InputStream и OutputStream у сокета:

```
s.getInputStream()
s.getOutputStream()
```

и с их помощью читаем и пишем данные

посланная в OutputStream строка придет в InputStream к пославшему и всем остальным клиентам, подключенным к серверу.

Answer (score 3):

Вы сначала определитесь с архитектурой чата:

1. peer-to-peer - то есть когда комп. соединяется с компом напрямую без посредника, например так организован BitTorrent
2. client-server, когда есть централизованный сервер и все общение идет через него, пример Skype, ICQ
3. Смешанная система - пример Yahoo Messenger

Comment: вообще то скайп еще до недавна был практически чистый p2p. И только с приходом Майкрософта он постепенно централизируется, но все равно он сейчас смешанный и ближе к p2p.

Comment: не знал - всегда почему то думал, что он чистый централизованный.

Answer (score -2):

"client-server, когда есть централизованный сервер и все общение идет через него, пример Skype, ICQ". 
Скайп реализован не за клиент-сервер в плане обмена временными данными (сообщения, поток аудио/видео). На сервере скайпа реализовано хранение только данных самого пользователя. 
Берите во внимание, когда в звонке 3 участника, то объявляется лидер звонка и все данные идут через него. Он становится сервером.
Чат - если написать человеку в оффлайне и выйти, то тот человек не получит этого сообщения, пока первый не будет в онлайне.